# IntelliJ + Scala error while importing ? [error] (/:dumpStructure) java.net.URISyntaxException:

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

There is no much to explain I will simple put a log part:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#fork-run_2.11;2.4.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#fork-run-protocol_2.11;2.4.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#run-support_2.11;2.4.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-pickling_2.11;0.10.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.json4s#json4s-core_2.11;3.2.10 ...
[info] Resolving org.json4s#json4s-ast_2.11;3.2.10 ...
[info] Resolving com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.spire-math#jawn-parser_2.11;0.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.spire-math#json4s-support_2.11;0.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.8 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-testkit_2.11;2.3.8 ...
[error] (*/*:dumpStructure) java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 10: file:///C:\Users\spec8/.m2/repository
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed 2017-01-14 16:26:55
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="C:\Users\spec8\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\log\sbt.last.log">C:\Users\spec8\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\log\sbt.last.log</a>
```

As you can see I'm using Windows any ideas what is cause of this one ? I see that Scala have some problem with path but I don't know why

Comment: Could you share your `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem, rollback to 2016.3.1 version of scala plugin and the problem goes away.

Download 2016.3.1 version and install it from disk.

[Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/1347-scala) the link for download.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot downgrade the plugin version because it requires that you also downgrade your IDE version. So a solution I found is that you have to edit your build.sbt file, and replace the following line:

"Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",

with a hard-coded path, absolutePath property uses Windows' path separator and the parser expects *nix separator. So replace it with this:

"Local Maven Repository" at "file:///C:/path/to/.m2/repository",//+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",

And it should work.